# NotImplementedError: Could not run 'torchvision::nms' with arguments from the 'CUDA' backend

Tags: pytorch, yolov5

```
import torch

# Model
model = torch.hub.load('ultralytics/yolov5','yolov5s',pretrained=True)
# model = torch.hub.load('ultralytics/yolov5:fix/relpath', 'yolov5s', force_reload=True)
# Images
imgs = ['https://ultralytics.com/images/zidane.jpg']  # batch of images

# Inferences
results = model(imgs)

# Results
results.print()
results.save()  # or .show()

results.xyxy[0]  # img predictions (tensor)
results.pandas().xyxy[0]  # imgl predictions (pandas)
```

and this is my torchvision version and torch version
0.15.2a0
2.0.1

but something wrong like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0UW06.png)
NotImplementedError: Could not run 'torchvision::nms' with arguments from the 'CUDA' backend. This could be because the operator doesn't exist for this backend, or was omitted during the selective/custom build process (if using custom build). If you are a Facebook employee using PyTorch on mobile, please visit https://fburl.com/ptmfixes for possible resolutions. 'torchvision::nms' is only available for these backends: [CPU, QuantizedCPU, BackendSelect, Python, FuncTorchDynamicLayerBackMode, Functionalize, Named, Conjugate, Negative, ZeroTensor, ADInplaceOrView, AutogradOther, AutogradCPU, AutogradCUDA, AutogradXLA, AutogradMPS, AutogradXPU, AutogradHPU, AutogradLazy, AutogradMeta, Tracer, AutocastCPU, AutocastCUDA, FuncTorchBatched, FuncTorchVmapMode, Batched, VmapMode, FuncTorchGradWrapper, PythonTLSSnapshot, FuncTorchDynamicLayerFrontMode, PythonDispatcher].

how to run this program

please help me thanks